# Mclaurin polynomial word problem

Tags: calculus

A narrow negatively charged ring of radius R exerts a force on a positively charged particle P located at distance x above the center of the ring of magnitude

$$F(x) = -\frac{kx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} $$

a) COmpute the third degree Maclaurin polynomial.

b) Show that F is about equal to $-(k/r^3)x to second order. This shows that when x is small F(x) behaves like a restoring force similar to the force exerted by a spring.

c) Show that F(x) is about equal to -k/x^2 when x is large by showing that the limit as x approaches infinity is $\frac{F(x)}{-k/x^2} = 1$

This just seems absurdly complex, I can do a I suppose but it would take several hours to get the third degree derivative. I don't know how to do it with constants like that, or how it is possible. The other two I have no clue what they are even saying.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it would take a while, with, for me, a high probability of error.

I do not know whether the following method is "allowed." (It gives the right answer.)

We will find the Maclaurin expansion of $\frac{1}{(R^2+x^2)^{3/2}}$, and then multiply every term by $-kx$.

So now we want the Maclaurin expansion of $\frac{1}{(R^2+x^2)^{3/2}}$, but we only need to go as far as the $x^2$ term, because of the multiplication later by $-kx$.

Instead, we find the Maclauring expansion of $\frac{1}{(R^2+u)^{3/2}}$, and plug in $x^2$ for $u$ at the end. What this means is that we will have to find the **first** derivative of $(R^2+u)^{-3/2}$, and that's all.